OS-WALK-EU errors
I have two errors when running OS-WALK-EU. First one is:numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype(' Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\walkability_plugin.py", line 311, in run walkability_instance.walkability_algorithm() File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\algorithm\walkability_algorithm.py", line 331, in walkability_algorithm class_list = setQuantiles(self.gridLayer, self.pop_field) File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\algorithm\walkability_algorithm.py", line 327, in setQuantiles perc.append(np.percentile(EWlist, i)) File "", line 5, in percentile File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3818, in percentile return _quantile_unchecked( File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3937, in _quantile_unchecked r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_quantile_ureduce_func, q=q, axis=axis, out=out, File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3515, in _ureduce r = func(a, **kwargs) File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4064, in _quantile_ureduce_func r = _lerp(x_below, x_above, weights_above, out=out) File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3961, in _lerp diff_b_a = subtract(b, a) numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype(' and the second one is _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:/DIPLOMSKI/tempDir/walkarea.geojson not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\walkability_plugin.py", line 311, in run
walkability_instance.walkability_algorithm()
File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\algorithm\walkability_algorithm.py", line 871, in walkability_algorithm
calculatePopDens()
File "C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\os_walk_eu_plugin\algorithm\walkability_algorithm.py", line 647, in calculatePopDens
processing.run("native:extractbyattribute",
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:/DIPLOMSKI/tempDir/walkarea.geojson not found
Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.22.14-Białowieża Białowieża, 4cde646c
Python Path:
C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\OpenTopography-DEM-Downloader
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.14\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.14\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\joinmultiplelines
C:\Users\Mateo\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
C:/Users/Mateo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin
I have tried changing properties of the data, shorting the path.
